# Java: Thread.stop thread without monitors

Tags: java, multithreading

Java's `Thread.stop` is unsafe because :

> "Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked"

This makes sense.  But, what if that thread is not holding any monitors set in application code, is it safe to use `Thread.stop`?  I understand it is bad practice to use `Thread.stop`, but it is not clear to me why it would be unsafe if the running code does not hold monitors.

Comment: From [`Thread#stop()`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()): "***Deprecated.**
This method is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread with Thread.stop causes it to unlock all of the monitors that it has locked (as a natural consequence of the unchecked ThreadDeath exception propagating up the stack). [...]*". See [this page by Oracle on the topic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) for alternatives.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be thinking a bit too narrowly at the affected objects here. It can be any monitor that the thread touches (which is essentially just an object accessed by more than one thread), or any object (in some cases, possibly even primitives) referenced by any of those monitors. *Any* one of those may be left in a broken state, depending on when Thread.stop() is called, with no vaguely easy way of finding out what exactly is broken.

If your `Thread` really doesn't touch *any* such objects, then technically it's "safe" - but that would be a very rare case, and an odd one too (since if the thread never interacts with any kind of state that can be referenced anywhere else, what's the point of it?)

Comment: I can envision a number of scenarios in which the thread does not interact with the calling main thread.  Perhaps it is a service thread that updates a database from a web-feed.  I am not defending using Thread.stop, but it only seems unsafe if there are application level monitors (3rd party code could introduce such monitors unwittingly though).

Comment: @adamM Ah, but in that case, depending on the DB implementation, you could end up corrupting the DB if you call Thread.stop half way through it writing some information out to disk - so it's then still potentially unsafe (but for a different reason.)

Comment: you have a point, but I would hope a DB would be able to handle an unexpected connection close.  From a DB perspective a stopped thread would look the same as a crashed client JVM.  A DB that corrupts under such crashes (either client JVM or stopped thread), would seem to be one very buggy DB, and certainly not ACID (or anywhere near it).

Comment: @adamM You're correct, I should have said "depending on database implementation" - if it was a connection to a remote database, then sure, it should be able to handle a connection close without corruption. If it were a DB running inside the same VM however (such as a HSQLDB instance), it may not be able to.